# Format json output with jq

Tags: json, jq, kubectl

I'm writing a script which will obtain certain info from my Kubernetes cluster.

The following command

```bash
kubectl get --context <my-context> svc --selector='<my-selectors>' -o json |
jq -r ' .items[]| {Name:.metadata.name, Port:.spec.ports[0].port} + {Group: "test", Group: "group name", SSLMode: "prefer", MaintenanceDB: "postgres"} '>file.json
```

will output something like this

```
{
  "Name": "db-name",
  "Port": 3000,
  "Group": "group name",
  "SSLMode": "prefer",
  "MaintenanceDB": "postgres"
}
{
  "Name": "db-name",
  "Port": 5432,
  "Group": "group name",
  "SSLMode": "prefer",
  "MaintenanceDB": "postgres"
}
```

I've been trying to get the above into the following format

```
{
  "Servers":{
    "1": {
      "Name": "db-name",
      "Port": 3000,
      "Group": "Server Group 1",
      "SSLMode": "prefer",
      "MaintenanceDB": "postgres"
    },
    "2": {
      "Name": "db-name",
      "Port": 5432,
      "Group": "Server Group 1",
      "SSLMode": "prefer",
      "MaintenanceDB": "postgres"
    }
  }
}
```

Only just discovered jq so the few things I've tried have been unsuccessful. Would be grateful for any pointers.

Comment: Sorry it's this jq - https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the stream of JSON objects shown in the question, the following jq filter will produce the desired output assuming the stream is somehow "slurped":

```
. as $in
| reduce range(0;length) as $i ({};.[$i+1|tostring] = $in[$i])
| {Servers: .}
```

To avoid having to call jq twice, you could wrap your filter in square brackets, and pipe that into the above; better yet, you can streamline everything, e.g. along the following lines:

```
.items
| [to_entries[]
   | {(.key+1|tostring): .value}
   | map_values(
      {Name:.metadata.name,
       Port:.spec.ports[0].port,
       Group: "group name",
       SSLMode: "prefer",
       MaintenanceDB: "postgres"}) ]
| {Servers: add}
```

Comment: Thanks that was super useful. I marked it as the answer as I was effectively asking how to add the items to a parent object. I used your second solution but pgadmin is being annoyingly strict in the format the server data is imported and doesn't like the square brackets after 'Servers:' - I tried to remove the outside [ ] but then I ended up with 'Servers:' for every group instead of 1 parent 'Servers:'

Comment: Solved the formatting issue with adding '| add' before '| {Servers" .}'